Client does not support authentication protocol 'auth_gssapi_client' requested by server in MariaDB-React ts
I have problem when i want start express server, i got the following error
Unable to connect to the database: ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: (conn:3, no: 45025, SQLState: 08004) Client does not support authentication protocol 'auth_gssapi_client' requested by server.
    at ConnectionManager.connect (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mariadb\connection-manager.js:100:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:222:24)
    at async F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:174:32 {
  parent: SqlError: (conn:3, no: 45025, SQLState: 08004) Client does not support authentication protocol 'auth_gssapi_client' requested by server.
      at module.exports.createFatalError (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\misc\errors.js:90:10)
      at Authentication.pluginHandler (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\authentication.js:274:20)
      at Authentication.dispatchAuthSwitchRequest (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\authentication.js:242:36)
      at Authentication.handshakeResult (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\authentication.js:62:14)
      at Authentication.onPacketReceive (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\authentication.js:40:17)
      at PacketInputStream.receivePacketBasic (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\io\packet-input-stream.js:85:9)
      at PacketInputStream.onData (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\io\packet-input-stream.js:135:20)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
      at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3) {
    sqlMessage: "Client does not support authentication protocol 'auth_gssapi_client' requested by server.",
    sql: null,
    fatal: true,
    errno: 45025,
    sqlState: '08004',
    code: 'ER_AUTHENTICATION_PLUGIN_NOT_SUPPORTED'
  },
  original: SqlError: (conn:3, no: 45025, SQLState: 08004) Client does not support authentication protocol 'auth_gssapi_client' requested by server.
      at module.exports.createFatalError (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\misc\errors.js:90:10)
      at Authentication.pluginHandler (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\authentication.js:274:20)
      at Authentication.dispatchAuthSwitchRequest (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\authentication.js:242:36)
      at Authentication.handshakeResult (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\authentication.js:62:14)
      at Authentication.onPacketReceive (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\authentication.js:40:17)
      at PacketInputStream.receivePacketBasic (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\io\packet-input-stream.js:85:9)
      at PacketInputStream.onData (F:\Code\Web\apr-ts\backend\node_modules\mariadb\lib\io\packet-input-stream.js:135:20)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
      at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3) {
    sqlMessage: "Client does not support authentication protocol 'auth_gssapi_client' requested by server.",
    sql: null,
    fatal: true,
    errno: 45025,
    sqlState: '08004',
    code: 'ER_AUTHENTICATION_PLUGIN_NOT_SUPPORTED'
  }
}

yes, i already follow the solution from the similiar questions before me, like i did
ALTER USER 'your_username'@'your_host' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD('your_password');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

and did
SELECT user, host, plugin FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'your_username';

but it's not working. i use sequelize as ORM. but when i just define my Database configuration in app.js (as my server file) and i run node app.js to start server, it's working.
Using this is working, but neither sequelize included.
const mariadb = require('mariadb');

const pool = mariadb.createPool({
    host: 'your_host',
    user: 'your_username',
    password: 'your_password',
    database: 'your_database',
    connectionLimit: 5
});

async function connectDatabase() {
    let conn;
    try {
        conn = await pool.getConnection();
        console.log("Connected to the database!");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", err);
    } finally {
        if (conn) conn.release(); // release to the pool
    }
}

connectDatabase();

while i use configuration db connection in different files. i define some db config like dbname, dbuser, dbhost, dbpassword, port, dbport in .env then it's read by config.js. which config.js provide data to database.js, and then reach the app.js.  like should my app.js as my server:
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');
const sequelize = require('./config/database');
const routerApi = require('./routes');

// Load environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Backend con NodeJS - Express + CRUD API REST + MySQL');
});

// Apply the routes
routerApi(app);

// Connect to the database and start the server
sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection to the database has been established successfully.');
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
        process.exit(1);  // Exit the process with failure code
    });

i try to connecting my database, to my backend and test it using postman, rather than json response,  the response is nothing, just refusing 8080 port, because i still fail to start my node express server,
Any response / suggestion will be very thankful!

Please stop using 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' after creating a user or grants, its not needed. To view a user use show create user 'your_username'@'your_host' - it contains more information than the backwords compatible mysql.user view.

@danblack Thank you for your suggestion, i need to know this.

a) You passed wrong password.
b) You used "root" user.
c) Your server is on Windows
If you're not doing either a) or b) or c), you won't see the error. I'd recommend not to do b). Yet bottom-line, seeing this error only means "I tried the password, it did not work, I used fallback, it did not work either, on different reason"

The database configuration i think nothing problem, because i declare it carefully in my .env and it's file's relaiyng to the app.js. And I have already to create new user for my db,  to try is it working, as you mention root user is have to avoided. But it still show the same error

MariaDB Connector/Node.js currently doesn't support the plugin auth_gssapi_client.
Feature request: CONJS-72 Implement auth_gssapi_client support

That's correct, thank you. but Is there no alternative solution there?

As a programmer you could implement it like the other node js plugins, and as a reference the c interface and the c gssapi interface.

Also MariaDB Plc might be persuaded to implement it if you contract them to do so.
